# How to store the user selected value from API response in a variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

User inputs a company's ID number and it will return them a list of addresses that belong to that company split in 3 objects (street, zip code, city).

When they click on one of those addresses, I want the 3 elements of the selected address to be stored in the postData() function:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-row v-if="ask_id">
          <v-text-field label="Enter the id_number" v-model="id_number"></v-text-field>
          <v-btn 
          @click="
          send_id_number();
          show_results()">
          </v-btn>
        </v-row>
        <v-row v-else>
          <v-select v-model="res_data"
          :items="filteredData" label="Places" :item-text="
          (item) => item.street + item.zip_code + item.city">
          </v-select>
        </v-row>
      </v-card-text>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  import axios from 'axios';
  
  export default {
    props: ["id"],
    data() {
      return {
        ask_id: true,
        id_number: null,
        res_object: [],
        res_data: [],
        places: []
      };
    },
    computed: {
        filteredData() {
        return this.res_object.places
          ? this.res_object.places.filter((g) => {
            return g.places_closed == false;
          })
          : [];
      },
      postData() {
        let data = {
            selected_street: this.?,
            selected_zip: this.?,
            selected_city: this.?,
            id_number: this.?
        }
        return data
      }
    },
    methods: {
      show_results() {
      this.mode = false
      },
      send_id_number() {
        axios.get(`https://api.places_url.com/${this.id_number}`)
        .then((response) => {
          this.res_object = response.data
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
        })
      }
    },
  };
  </script>
```

However whatever I try to do tells me `TypeError: undefined is not an object`. I'm missing a step but I'm not sure what it is.

structure of the api response:

```
{
    "company_id": 123456789,
    "places":[
        {"street":"8 main street",
        "zip_code":"303",
        "city":"RandomCity",
        "places_closed":false
        },
        {"street":"10 main street",
        "zip_code":"404",
        "city":"RandomCity",
        "places_closed":false
        },
        {"street":"11 main street",
        "zip_code":"505",
        "city":"RandomCity",
        "places_closed":false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you provide a valid id for the API call?

Comment: unfortunately no since it's an API with restricted access but I've added an exemple of response in my op

Comment: your response object seems wrong can you verify once for me?

Comment: edited sorry, wrong copy paste!

Comment: I edited the answer. are you looking for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can try something like the below add return-object props in v-select and then you get res_data v-model as an object.**

```
    <template>
    <div>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-row v-if="ask_id">
          <v-text-field label="Enter the id_number" v-model="id_number"></v-text-field>
          <v-btn 
          @click="
          send_id_number();
          show_results()">
          </v-btn>
        </v-row>
        <v-row v-else>
          <v-select @change="postData()" v-model="res_data"
          :items="filteredData" label="Places" :item-text="
          (item) => item.street +' '+ item.zip_code +' '+ item.city" return-object>
          </v-select>
        </v-row>
      </v-card-text>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  import axios from 'axios';
  
  export default {
    props: ["id"],
    data() {
      return {
        ask_id: false,
        id_number: null,
        res_object: 
        {
    "company_id": 123456789,
    "places":[
        {"street":"8 main street",
        "zip_code":"303",
        "city":"RandomCity",
        "places_closed":false
        },
        {"street":"10 main street",
        "zip_code":"404",
        "city":"RandomCity",
        "places_closed":false
        },
        {"street":"11 main street",
        "zip_code":"505",
        "city":"RandomCity",
        "places_closed":false
        }
    ]
},
        res_data: [],
        places: []
      };
    },
    computed: {
        filteredData() {
        return this.res_object.places
          ? this.res_object.places.filter((g) => {
            return g.places_closed == false;
          })
          : [];
      },

      
    },
    
    methods: {
      postData() {
        console.log(this.res_data);
        return this.res_data;
      },
      show_results() {
      this.mode = false
      },
      send_id_number() {
        console.log(this.id_number);
        axios.get(`https://api.places_url.com/${this.id_number}`)
        .then((response) => {
          this.res_object = response.data
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
        })
      }
    },
  };
  </script>
```

Let me know if you want something else

Comment: It works and I manage to get the data but I cannot manage to parse the item into the 3 items (street, zip code, city) in postData(), do you have an idea on how I should do it? And thanks a lot for the help

Comment: i did not get your point can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: the res_data object consists of 3 elements `item.street + item.zip_code + item.city`. So I would like postData() to take this into account and return:

`postData() {
        let data = {
            selected_street: this.item.street,
            selected_zip: this.item.zip_code,
            selected_city: this.item.city,
        }
        return data
      }

Comment: already postData() is returning which you want add return-object in v-select i already mentioned in my answer go through it you will get it.